# Getting the value of a custom date field in openerp?

Tags: python, odoo

I added a new date field in the quotation form via the developer's mode. Now i want to get the field's value by retrieving it via python. The problem is that the string it is retrieving is 'False', a boolean value, i checked it. My code is correct because when i retrieved an existing date field on the form, it is retrieving it correctly. The problem is arising only with the custom field that i added. How can i solve this? i am using openerp 7....

```
 prod_obj = self.pool.get('sale.order')
 products_ids = prod_obj.browse(cr, uid,uid,context=context)
 expected_date = products_ids['x_expected_payment_date']
```

'x_expected_payment_date' is the custom field i added. it is displaying correctly on the form btw.

Answer (score 1):

You are browsing the sale order using the user ID so I presume you are getting a sale order that doesn't have a date set (or doesn't exist).

Try:

```
 sale_order = self.pool.get('sale.order').browse(cr, uid, my_sale_order_id, context=context)
 expected_date = sale_order.x_expected_payment_date
```

Note I assume you have your sale order id (my_sale_order_id) somewhere.

Also note that this code assumes it is an int or long.  If you pass browse a single ID, you get a single browse record back; if you pass it a list of IDs you get a list of browse records back.

Comment: your answer is great thanks a lot...but how can i get the sale order id of the current transaction?

Comment: Please note that the value is not inserted into the database....it has to be retrieved as the user has entered in the form without submitting the form....